# Issue with HTML displayed in email sent from PHP

Tags: php, html, css, pear, mime

I'm using the Pear PHP mail library to send HTML emails (mainly to hotmail). I'm having issues with the CSS functioning correctly. At the moment when the message is received the CSS is in the body of the message and the styles are not applied.

The code is as follows:

```
$message = "<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
        body {
    font:12px/1.4em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:700px;
    margin:50px auto;
    padding:0;
}

a {
    color:#326EA1;
    text-decoration:underline;
    padding:0 1px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

div.header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}

div.item {
    padding:5px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}  
</style>
</head>
    </body>";

// PARSE    
    $limit = 9;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $news[$x]['title']);
        $link = $news[$x]['link'];
        $description = $news[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($news[$x]['date']));
        $message .= '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        $message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }

    $message .="</body> </html>";       

foreach($email_add_arr as $name => $email)
{

$crlf = "\n";
$from = "";
$to = "$name <$email>";
$subject = "News - $date";
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "";
$password = "";

// Creating the Mime message
$mime = new Mail_mime();

// Setting the body of the email
$mime->setHTMLBody($message);
$body = $mime->get();   

$headers = array (
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject,
'MIME-Version: 1.0',
                    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                    array ('host' => $host,
                     'port' => $port,
                     'auth' => true,
                     'username' => $username,
                     'password' => $password
                     ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
}
```

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the ONE time that you'll see inline styles being advocated. Email services are a lot like internet browsers.  They all handle defaults differently.  With browsers being a lot more friendly than email services.

Comment: http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 7):

You can only apply inline styles in the mails.

For example:

```
<div style="float:left; padding: 10px;">demo</div>
```

Comment: one small caveat - some mail clients will support a style tag but in order to be cross compatible you should use inline.

Comment: Yeah that's great thanks however when the email is sent the email body looks like this: <html>
<body style='font: 12px/1.4em Verdana, sans-serif;color: #333;background-color: #fff;width: 700px;margin: 50px auto;padding: 0;'><p><strong><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/1j0rso/good_point/" title="Good point.">Good point.</a></strong><br /><p><table> <tr><td> <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/1j0rso/good_point/"><img  ETC....... hotmail isn't picking up that it is HTML code...

Comment: Your message was cut. Like how?

Comment: @DanielPilch that is another question. I answered your first question. I would recommend you to open another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use inline CSS. Try this tool http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

Answer (score 0):

@alvaro's answer is correct.  In addition though, a good resource for what exactly is supported in each client is this http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

It addresses

- selectors
- text & fonts
- color & background
- box model
- lists
- tables

for all relevant mail clients